# How to show typing indicator in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, xmpp, stanza.io

Hi I a chat application in `Reactjs`and `Redux`. Currently I am not using any database, I am storing all the users in my `redux store`. I am sending the message and receiving the message using `xmpp stanza.js`. Now I want to show a `typing indicator` in my chat application. I don't have any idea how to implement that thing. You can imagine, I have simply a list of users in my `Redux` .These users have some property

```
Users={
  Id:123,
  LastMessagebody:"hii",
  Messagread:true,
  MessageAt:12:40Pm
  From:56
}
```

Comment: can u define what is a typing indicator, like "I" in an input box ? Then how this has anything to do with the rest of data? just curious.

Comment: A typing indicator is a small interface component used to notify the user that the person on the other side is currently typing a message into the text box.

Comment: then your question is a bit big my friend. You need to paste some code. In general, depending on how the chat is designed, suppose it's a socket, when the data arrives, it has an  event you can subscribe to.  But of course this depends on the code.